# Loop through custom object array in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript

I started playing a little bit with TypeScript. I have created two classes (Student and Listview). I am trying to loop over the array with the student objects I created but somehow it doesn't work.

```
class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName, public middleInitial, public lastName) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
}

class Listview {
    items: Array<Student>;
    constructor(public item_list: Array<Student>) {}

    log(): void {
        var items = this.items;
        for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
          console.log(items[i]);
        }
    }

}

var list = new Listview(
    [new Student("Jane", "M.", "User"),
    new Student("Hans", "M.", "Muster"),
    new Student("Fritz", "B.", "Muster")]
);
list.log();
```

I get this warning in the console:

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKKK4.png)

How do I need to access the array to read the properties of each student object?

Greetings
Orkun

Comment: You do not set `items` in your code. You just initialize `item_list` in the constructor.

Comment: @Orkun It's considered good etiquette to put the code / console output directly in your StackOverflow question. I'd recommend editing it to include the code :)

Comment: @SebastianSebald Thanks. Silly mistake by me, didn't saw it somehow that item_list is containing my objects since i made it public :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ListView` should look like this, in order to correctly initialize `items`:

```
class Listview {
    constructor(public items: Array<Student>) {}

    log(): void {
        var items = this.items;
        for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
          console.log(items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```